# How to replace index value with user requirement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'll make it simple, if i have a list in my ng-repeat

```
1. A & index[0]<br>
 2. B & index[1]<br>
 3. C & index[2]<br>
 4. D & index[3]<br><br>
```

and i have a inputfield for user to Prioritize der list 
ex:
1. B Prior to 1st place... then

```
B & index[0]<br>
  A & index[1]<br>
  C & index[2]<br>
  D & index[3]<br>
```

2. D Prior to 2st place... then

```
A & index[0]<br>
  D & index[1]<br>
  B & index[2]<br>
  C & index[3]<br>
```

how to do....? do help  *thanks in advance*

Comment: Can you post a plunker with your accomplishment on this task so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array, place all your options in an array and when a user change the order you can replace the order of the elements in the array.

You can apply this code for the switch:

```
var temp = array[currentIndex];
array[currentIndex] = array[newIndex];
array[newIndex] = temp;
```